# Android Studio only builds apk for x86_64 native platforms - don't know why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, release-builds

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 trying to make a release build with following splits

```
splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' //select ABIs to build APKs for
                universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
            }
    }
```

This is generating the following files

```
app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
app-universal-release.apk
app-x86_64-release.apk
app-x86-release.apk
```

This seems fine but when I try to upload any of the above apk to playstore, I see native platforms as x86_64 for every one of them and also the number of supported devices seems to be 15.

[APK Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxXh3.png)

I have no idea what went wrong since the debug apk is working fine on the devices and emulators. So, I would appreciate if anybody could tell me what could be a cause for it and ways to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Concepts

Have a look at the Rules for multiple APKs:

`Each APK must have a different version code, specified by the android:versionCode attribute`

Also might be worth reading this whole document, specifically "Using a Single APK Instead"

Comment: https://blog.be-bound.com/apk-split-tutorial/ gives a good overview

Comment: @GavinHarris Thank you for the comment. It turned out that a library had dependency on x86_64. After excluding the library from the build. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: @eth-new-user It would be nice if you could say which library gave you that problem.